# What is being said in this audio clip from the movie The Wolf Brigate?

Tags: translation, listening

I'm trying to understand what is being said in this audio clip taken from the movie Illang: The Wolf Brigade. I know that this movie should be available on Netflix with korean subtitles but sadly I don't own a subscription, so I'm asking here reporting the timings of each sentence in the movie, just in case it may be helpful. They're all pretty short though!

Timing: 00:25:56,638 [Clip](https://instaud.io/3wwz)

Timing: 00:26:08,025 [Clip](https://instaud.io/3wwE)

Timing: 00:35:28,752 [Clip](https://instaud.io/3wwA)

Timing: 01:27:16,064 [Clip](https://instaud.io/3wwy)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My translations are more or less literal, so that you can get the gist of the Korean expression. I don't think the English subtitles wander too much.

### Audio 1

> 여기서 진짜 뼈가 부서지도록 쏘고 달리고 뒹굴고 했었는데

or [...] 뒹굴곤 했었는데, [...] 뒹굴고 그랬었는데. Whatever the exact transcription is, the meaning doesn't change.

#### Translation

> We used to shoot, run, and roll so that we nearly broke our bones in this place.

Maybe the speaker is talking about himself only, so not "we/our" but "I/my"? I can't tell from the context.

#### Subtitles

> Korean: 여기서 뼈가 부서지도록 쏘고 달리고 뒹굴었었는데.
>
> English: I punched and shot and ran myself to death in this place.

### Audio 2

> 여긴 진짜 안 된다.

This should be understood in line with the previous phrase, so the full sentence is "나는 이 지옥도 시간이 지나면 추억이 되나 했는데, 여긴 진짜 안 된다."

#### Translation

> I thought this hell would fade out to (good) memories as time went by, *but this place doesn't ever be (a good memory).*

The *emphasis* is what your clip exactly matches.

#### Subtitles

> Korean: 난 이 지옥도 시간이 지나면 추억이 되나 했는데, 여긴 진짜 안 된다.
>
> English: I thought, as time passed, I'd even grow fond of hell. *But this place was too much.*

### Audio 3

> 초면에 제가 별 얘기를 다 하네요. 요즘 제가 좀 그래요, 마음이 소금밭이라.

#### Translation

> I barely know you and see how I babble. Maybe because I *left my heart at the salt fields.*

The emphasis matches "마음이 소금밭", but it doesn't seem to be a common idiom.

It may be a reference to the best-selling book [마음이 소금밭인데 오랜만에 도서관에 갔다.](https://books.google.com/books/about/%EB%A7%88%EC%9D%8C%EC%9D%B4_%EC%86%8C%EA%B8%88%EB%B0%AD%EC%9D%B8%EB%8D%B0_%EC%98%A4%EB%9E%9C%EB%A7%8C%EC%97%90.html?id=iZDCAwAAQBAJ) The publisher's review explains the expression, "how pale does a salt field shines, and how painful would it be if there your heart lies."

#### Subtitles

> Korean: 초면에 제가 별 얘기를 다 하네요. 요즘 마음이 소금밭이라 좀 그래요.
>
> English: Listen to me blabber because my heart's gone sour these days.

### Audio 4

> 이렇게 발표할 거야?

#### Translation

> Is this how you're going to publish it?

#### Subtitles

> Korean: 이렇게 발표할 거야?
>
> English: Is this how you'll announce it?

Answer (score 1):

1. 여기서 진짜 뼈가 부서지도록 쏘고 날리고 뒹굴고 했었는데..
2. XX은 진짜 안된다. (I don't know what XX is but I think it's simillar to "여긴(here)")
3. 초면에 제가 별 이야기를 다하네요, 요즘 제가 그래요. 마음이 조금 까칠한..
4. 이렇게 발표할거야?